# Why some normal comments get flagged

Tags: discussion

Getting 10k is teaching me a lot about what to do and what not to do on the site. :)

I just saw something weird... a post with 6 upvotes had a comment beneath it:

> +1 Best answer

and the comment was flagged. This seems to happen quite often actually (there's always a few legitimate comments marked as spam on the flagged page); it wasn't just this particular case.

I'm curious: why are these flagged? Are they by accident, or is there some violation that's happening that I'm not noticing?

Comment: I'd guess that someone went to upvote the comment and mis-clicked. Or someone hates comments like that and thinks they're just noise.

Comment: @Anna: And pressed the OK button by accident too?

Comment: @Mehrdad or hit enter, but yeah it'd have to be pretty unlikely for that to happen as often as you are indicating that it happens

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah... it's definitely possible to happen by accident, but the thing was that I noticed it several times today on the page, where legit comments seemed to have this. I didn't post any examples because I didn't want the non-10k users to suddenly see that their comments had been flagged, but do you think I should post a couple examples here later if I see them again?

Comment: Congrats on hitting 10k :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Haha thank youu! :) Now just 278K to go!

Comment: Someone needs to let us flag these flags as the **real** noise among the legit flags.

Comment: @BoltClock: Metaflags! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to stay away from flagging comments unless they're particularly egregious, but - what does that comment really add? You can upvote - what's the point of telling everyone that you upvoted?

Comment: It doesn't technically add anything, but what was weird to me was that the comment *below* it actually got an upvote for saying pretty much the same thing...

Comment: @Mehrdad - not really. The second comment added useful content. And nothing prevents comments from being both upvoted *and* flagged. Happens a lot, actually.

Comment: Yeah I guess so... I'll try to post another example soon if I see it. It's a great learning process to see what goes on on the site btw! :)